# Why is the devise method encrypted_password= undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to set up devise for my admin model. The admin model inherits from Author. I've done all the devise setup that is suggested in the documentation and run all migrations etc. My models are as below:

Author Class:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :articles
  validates :first_name, :surname, :email, presence: true
end
```

Admin Class:

```
class Admin < Author
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Devise Migration:

```
class DeviseCreateAdmins < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:admins) do |t|
    ## Database authenticatable
    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

    ## Recoverable
    t.string   :reset_password_token
    t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

    ## Rememberable
    t.datetime :remember_created_at

    ## Trackable
    t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
    t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
    t.inet     :current_sign_in_ip
    t.inet     :last_sign_in_ip

    ## Confirmable
    # t.string   :confirmation_token
    # t.datetime :confirmed_at
    # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

    ## Lockable
    # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
    # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
    # t.datetime :locked_at


    t.timestamps null: false
  end

  add_index :admins, :email,                unique: true
  add_index :admins, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  #add_index :admins, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
  #add_index :admins, :unlock_token,         unique: true
end
```

Schema showing `encrypted_password` in DB.

```
create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
```

The error I receive when trying to create an Admin in one of my tests, or in rails console, is as follows:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `encrypted_password=' for #<Admin:0x007fc1c3269e18>
```

The test being used is:

```
   scenario 'Signing in with correct credentials' do
    Admin.create(first_name: "Jonathan", surname: "Sayer", email: "test@email.com",
              password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
     visit '/login'
     fill_in 'Email', with: "test@email.com"
     fill_in 'Password', with: "password"
     click_button "Log in"
     expect(page.current_path).to eq root_path
   end
```

With the error message:

```
1) Signing in  Signing in with correct credentials
 Failure/Error:
   Admin.create(first_name: "Jonathan", surname: "Sayer", email: "test@email.com",
                password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `encrypted_password=' for #<Admin:0x007fc1c3269e18>
 # /Users/jonathansayer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/devise-3.5.6/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:43:in `password='
 # ./spec/features/logging_in_and_out_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to set `encrypted_password` field? You're not supposed to do that. Show the code.

Comment: Nope, I'm just trying to use the encrypted_password method that comes with devise. All code that involves anything to do with devise in my code base is shown above.

Comment: Can you please show the console command or test expression that leads to the error?

Comment: @JoeEssey Now showing. :)

Comment: Looks like it could be a migration issue.  Please see this thread:  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/589

Comment: Migrations have been re-run. I dropped the database and did a complete reset. Same issue.

Comment: I know you said this does not work in console either. But if it is only test then, maybe it is rake db:test:prepare

Comment: Sorry @sonnyhe2002 No Joy. Same error message :(

Comment: There is an "annotate" gem, that will show exactly what is in your models, can you use that then "annotate -i -p before"

Comment: Or it you try saving it the long way what would happen? Admin,ew

Comment: Definitely a case of a migration issue

Comment: ``Admin.new(first_name: "Jonathan", surname: "Sayer", email: "test@email.com",
2.3.0 :002 >                         password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")`` still has the same error.

Comment: @JonSayerCan you post the output of `Admin.new.respond_to?(:encrypted_password=)` just to be sure

Comment: @Alfie I suspect so too but can't find a problem with the migrations. The schema also shows the devise attributes in the DB.

Comment: ``2.3.0 :001 > Admin.new.respond_to?(:encrypted_password=)
 => false ``

Comment: Which is weird considering other devise attributes are there:``2.3.0 :003 > Admin.new.respond_to?(:password)
 => true `` and ``2.3.0 :004 > Admin.new.respond_to?(:password_confirmation)
 => true ``

Comment: could you try doing : `db:migrate:reset` which runs db:drop db:create db:migrate

Comment: @Alfie Still the same issue I'm afraid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109854/discussion-between-alfie-and-jonsayer).

Comment: Or it you try saving it the long way what would happen? admin = Admin.new; admin.password =""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Add `self.table_name = "admins"` to your `Admin` model to fix the error.

**Explanation**

I see that the `Admin` model is inherited from the `Author` model. Which btw is not recommended unless you are trying to implement STI (single table inheritance).
Which is not the case here as you have tables for both the models. And here lies the actual problem.

You see by default ActiveRecord connects a Rails model to it's corresponding table in the DB using the pluralized name of the model.

So in this case for the `Author` model it corresponds to the `authors` table in the DB. Now since `Admin` is inherited from `Author` it too is connected to `authors` table.

And that is why all the fields you expect to be present in the `admins` table is not present. Because right now the `Admin` model knows only the fields in `authors` table

The fix would be to explicitly specify the table name for the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and your help :)